# How do I change the default text for PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

By default is showing a text that looks like this:

YOUR-FIELD-NAME-HERE field value. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 0):

We are using custom form templates and it turns out that we were incorrectly setting the form field mode to edit instead if new mode:

> < PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField runat="server" id="ff2" 
>   FieldName="Answer" <strike>ControlMode="Edit"</strike>  / >